# Laravel php artisan make:auth doesn't create migration files

Tags: laravel-5

After creating my Laravel 5.2 App I added auth to it but there are no migration files for users and password_resets.

Comment: these migration files should be included by default in the new Laravel 5.2 install. See 5.2 branch on Github: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.2/database/migrations

Comment: yes i know .. while working on a  Laravel project i need to add auth so i ran this command 
php artisan make:auth 
all files updated but no migration files to add new tables to my existing DB

Comment: so you'are working on the existing project, where someone deleted the migrations for users & password_resets, and now you want to add these migrations back?

Comment: never existed before

Answer (score 0):

Laravel by default gives two migration files with these file names 
1. 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table " date is always the same " 
2. 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table 
Path for migrations is \The_App\database\migrations

Laravel Auth uses these migrations for the authentication process. It doesn't creates new migrations ...